# Managing and referencing items in an immutable store

Tags: functional-programming, scala, immutability

I have some things (I'll call them `Item`s) that can either be passed around directly or referred to by reference. For the items that are referred to, there is a storage from which the items can be obtained.

My problem is that I want to keep the storage immutable, but I can't figure out how to do so elegantly. It seems that to work with the items and the storage at the same time, every method has to accept the existing storage as input and then output an updated storage alongside the item. This is how this looks in code:

```scala
sealed trait Item

case class ItemRef(id: String) extends Item

case class ItemDef(propA: String, propB: Boolean) extends Item

type ItemStore = Map[String, ItemDef]

def makeItem(rawItemData: Map[String, String], itemStore: ItemStore): (Item, ItemStore) = {
  val id = generateItemId(data) // Some unique ID for this item

  if(shouldItemDefBeUsed(data)) { // Ie, is the item small or simple?
    (buildItemDef(data), this)
  } else if(data contains id) { // Avoid building the complex def unless needed
    (ItemRef(id), this)
  } else {
    val itemDef = buildItemDef(data)
    (ItemRef(id), this.copy(items = items + (id -> itemDef)))
  }
}
```

In the code above, `makeItem` is really annoying to use since it has to take the store as input and returns two outputs:

```scala
val initialStore: ItemStore = Map.empty[String, ItemDef]
val (itemA, storeWithA) = makeItem(itemAData, initialStore)
val (itemB, storeWithAAndB) = makeItem(itemAData, storeWithA)
```

Besides being annoying to use, this is also error prone:

```scala
val store: ItemStore = Map.empty[String, ItemDef]
val (itemA, storeWithA) = makeItem(itemAData, store)
val (itemB, storeWithAAndB) = makeItem(itemAData, store) // !! Forgot to use updated store
```

And it's not very readable to make a collection of items:

```scala
def makeItems(rawItemsData: List[Map[String, String]], itemStore: ItemStore): (List[Item], ItemStore) = {
  rawItemsData.foldLeft(List.empty[Item], itemStore)({case ((items, store), currentItemData) => 
    val (currentItem, updatedStore) = makeItem(currentItemData, store)
    (items :+ currentItem, updatedStore)
  })
}
```

Is there a better pattern for doing this? I feel like there must be some cleaner way that doesn't involve returning tuples and taking extra arguments, but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: I don't think this is appropriate for Code Review. The code, as posted, does not compile. (Where does `data` come from? What does `this` refer to?) According to the Help Center page [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), this site is for "_questions about code that already works correctly (to the best of your knowledge)_", and also "_questions should not contain ... hypothetical code_".

Comment: To the best of your knowledge does the code work as expected? If not then @jwvh is correct.

Comment: @jwvh I wasn't sure it it was a good fit here or not. What would be a better site for it? The example I posted doesn't compile because I left some specific implementation details out because my question doesn't need them. The code does work though, and I am just looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: Code submitted on CodeReview should be ready and prepared for just that, a full code review, where it might be evaluated for its efficiency, safety, resilience, style, etc. If there's only one aspect that you're really interested in then [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is probably a better platform where they're a little more tolerant of partial and stubbed out code. That being said, you still need to post _enough_ code to confidently *demonstrate* the issue you're asking about.